# Message Queue for 'grouped' jobs e.g. notifications

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

Say I have an app that send an email to a user when something interesting in the system happens.  The system would add a `sendNotification` job to a message queue, which when processed sends out the email.

I want to be able to add these jobs to the queue whenever something interesting happens, but have the system wait for 10 minutes to gather and group all these notifications into one email, rather than send out multiple email within that short timeframe.

How would this be implemented in a system such as RabbitMQ?  As far as I can tell delay functionality isn't built in for a start, and you can't update messages once they are sent.  So are there any patterns recommended for implementing this kind of thing?

Comment: Do some sort of message aggregation?

Comment: Yes, that's part of what I'm wondering how to do.